# Ignore SQL errors when creating jobs

Tags: sql

I am copying the SQL Agent jobs from our production SQL2008 server to a D/R server by scripting CREATE statements on the PROD server, and executing the generated T-SQL on the D/R server. This works fine except for jobs that reference sprocs in databases that are mirrored. In this case, I get an error like this:

**Msg 954, Level 14, State 1, Line 2
The database "dbname" cannot be opened. It is acting as a mirror database.**

Is there a way to have SQL ignore these errors and create the job? I could find no SET statements that do this. I am trying to avoid breaking and re-establishing the mirrors for any of the DBs affected.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you copy down the sprocs as well so your D/R environment mirrors production?

Comment: All the DBs and their sprocs exist on the D/R server, but the DBs are in a "Mirror, Synchronized / Restoring" state which makes them not accessible.